# Resize Buffered Image - resize by multiple of 2

Tags: java, resize, bufferedimage

I'm looking to resize a small pixel image - 16x16 to 512x512. Is there any library that already does this?

I have looked at `imgscalr` and `Thumbnailator` but they produce a smooth output which I am trying to avoid.

To illustrate:

```
a b
c d

a a b b
a a b b
c c d d
c c d d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an external library for this.

This should do the trick:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Image scaledImage = img.getScaledInstance(512, 512, BufferedImage.SCALE_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Glad I could help. :)You should mark this question as answered though.

Comment: Alright, sorry for my impatience! I'm still new to this site, which is why I didn't know that you had to wait. :D